# VBA code to fill in IE dropdowns sometimes crashing

Tags: vba

The following code navigates to a quoting page and then starts to fill in some dropdown lists. This is aided by a function which I've pasted after this.

```
Sub GetQuote()

rowstart = 2

Do Until Cells(rowstart, 1).Value = ""

Dim IE As Object

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.navigate ("https://www.aami.com.au/secure/comprehensive-car-insurance-   get-a-quote.html")

IE.Visible = True

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readystate = 4

Set d = IE.Document

SelectOption d, "vehicleYearOfManufactureList", Cells(rowstart, 1).Value    
SelectOption d, "vehicleMakeList", Cells(rowstart, 2).Value
SelectOption d, "vehicleModelList", Cells(rowstart, 3).Value
SelectOption d, "vehicleTransmissionList", Cells(rowstart, 4).Value
SelectOption d, "vehicleNumberOfCylindersList", Cells(rowstart, 5).Value
SelectOption d, "vehicleBodyTypeList", Cells(rowstart, 6).Value

'then there is some more code, but it's irrelevant to my question here

IE.Quit
Loop

End Sub
```

The rowstart variable refers to a row in an excel spreadsheet where I have built my vehicles whose details I want to enter into this quote page.

So when rowstart = 2, then Cells(rowstart, 1) refers to cell A2 and in this cell would be some vehicle year-of-manufacture such as 2012.

And here is the function that links in:

```
Function SelectOption(doc, strID, strText)

Dim e
Set e = doc.getElementById(strID)

If e Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Could not find ID = " & strText
    Exit Function
End If

Dim o
For Each o In e.Options
    If StrComp(o.Text, strText, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        o.Selected = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next

If e.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Could not set value of " & strID & " to " & strText
    Exit Function
End If

Dim objEvent
Set objEvent = doc.createEvent("HTMLEvents") 
objEvent.initEvent "change", False, True 
e.dispatchEvent objEvent 

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))

SelectOption = True

End Function
```

A lot of the vehicles I've built are accepted. But sometimes one causes the programme to crash. For example, 2003, Ford, F250, M, DT6, C/chas (the values of the elements for this vehicle). I've checked these against the source code to make sure they are available values for this vehicle and the spelling is correct with no spaces etc. I've also manually checked that I can input these and complete a quote. I've also increased the delay in the fire-event function and then changed the values of the elements to slightly different combinations but to no avail.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Define: "crash" - does IE hard-crash or does your program fail with a VBA error message? Or something else?

Comment: Sorry, crash isn't the right word. When the programme loops to the row  (which has 2003, Ford, F250, M, DT6, C/chas), I get a msgbox defined in the function. In this example the first one is: "Could not set value of vehicle transmission list to M". After clicking it, similar message boxes will therefore subsequently display for the number-of-cylinders and  body-type dropdowns. It seems to always be the vehicle transmission value that triggers this. So it's not really crashing - it's just not accepting my vehicle via code in spite of it being accepted when I manually input the verified details

Comment: I might be wrong but it seems like the value that's getting inputted for transmission is accepted when there is only one option to choose from. When there are two more options it fails to accept the value that is being inputted.

Comment: @Bond - seems that tip you once suggested may prove useful. I changed some of the code to use the SelectedIndex property and it's looking promising. Will test this a bit more and then hopefully I can post an answer

Comment: @chris - When I bring this page up, the transmission option shows `"Manual"`, not `"M"`, as it sounds like you're passing. Did you try using: `SelectOption d, "vehicleTransmissionList", "Manual"`?

Comment: @Bond - Thanks for taking a look. I've been passing M and A for other vehicles and that has worked. The source code for this element is `<option value="M">Manual</option>`, so I think "Manual" is just a label or description? I'll try putting in Manual just to see if it works although I ended up using the SelectedIndex property (which doesn't fail thankfully)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not so sure this is an answer as such, but it enables to me to deal with the problem I had in a sort of workaround way. Instead of setting the value to string pasted in a spreadsheet, I've used the Selected.Index property.

For example:

```
IE.Document.GetElementByID("vehicleTransmissionList").SelectedIndex = 2 'In the case of M where it is the second option in drop down list. 1 would have been used for the first option, A
```

I've then just inserted fire-event code after this, thus removing the function I pasted above.